# Different output on different compilers

Tags: c++

Why does the following code prints different results on different compilers?

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() { std::cout << "::foo() \n"; }

namespace Foo
{
   struct Bar
   {
      friend void foo() { std::cout << "Bar::foo() \n"; }
      void bar() { foo(); }
      void baz();
   };

   void Bar::baz() { foo(); }
}

int main()
{
   Foo::Bar instance;
   instance.bar();
   instance.baz();
}
```

**Output**

gcc 4.7.2

> ```
> ::foo()
> ::foo()
> ```

MSVC-10.0

> ```
> Bar::foo()
> Bar::foo()
> ```

MSVC-11.0

> ```
> error C3861: 'foo': identifier not found
> error C3861: 'foo': identifier not found
> ```

Who is right? And why is it so?

Comment: Btw, you print `Bar::foo` but the function being defined there is `Foo::foo`. It's a free function in namespace `Foo`, not a member of `Bar`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop Oh, yeah, thanks. But this is not my question anyway

Answer (score 2):

I think gcc is right:

7.3.1.2/3 in C++11:

> If a friend declaration in a non-
>   local class ﬁrst declares a class or function the friend class or
>   function is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. The name of
>   the friend is not found by unqualiﬁed lookup (3.4.1) or by qualiﬁed
>   lookup (3.4.3) until a matching declaration is provided in that
>   namespace scope (either before or after the class deﬁnition

C++03 has similar language in the same place.

I'm not sure why MSVC-11 fails to find `::foo`, but I suppose you *could* read this text to mean that the name `foo` can't be looked up at all. I think the intended meaning is that the name in the innermost enclosing namespace can't be found, but the identically-spelled name in the outer scope can. But if Microsoft wants to argue the intended meaning I'm not the person they'd argue it with.

MSVC-10 is wrong, because it found a name that the standard specifically says is not found. So the explanation for the MSVC-11 behavior might be as simple as "it was reported as a bug in 10, they tried to fix it and went too far".

Anyway, the fix is to introduce a declaration of `foo` in namespace `Foo`:

```
namespace Foo
{
   void foo(); // this is a matching declaration
   struct Bar
   {
      friend void foo() { std::cout << "Bar::foo() \n"; }
      void bar() { foo(); }
      void baz();
   };

   void Bar::baz() { foo(); }
}
```

This makes gcc find the friend function. I haven't tested on any version of MSVC.

Comment: So, how can i call friend function in such kind of situation?

Comment: @Nikita: put a matching declaration in namespace scope before the class definition. Also note that AFAIK such a friend function *can* be found by ADL (that is, it could if it had any relevant arguments), which is why you don't need to declare operator overloads separately from their definition as friends.

Comment: I say "AFAIK" ADL finds it: that's the very next sentence after the bit I quoted :-)

Comment: Please, can you post an example with "matching declaration in namespace scope before the class definition"? Do you mean something like this? http://liveworkspace.org/code/1l2Wz3$0